# overlay height not adjusting to content

Tags: html, css

How do I go about getting this html/ css fixed so that the top div does not overlap the bottom div. The top div will not grow although the overlay content changes and it remains at the min-height of 60px;

```
<style>
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.relative:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.overlay-outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

.overlay-inner {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.overlay-content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
 </style>
 <div style="width: 350px;">
<div>
    <div class="relative" style="min-height: 60px;">
        <div class="overlay-outer ng-isolate-scope">
            <div class="overlay-inner">
                <div class="overlay-content">
                    <div class="padding-bottom-5 ng-binding ng-scope" data-ng-if="line1">There     are no unpaid items.</div>
                    <div class="padding-bottom-5 ng-binding ng-scope" data-ng-if="line2">content   content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid black; background: blue; color: white;">
Some text here that should not be overlapped, yet it is overlapping ...
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please put your code in JS Fiddle like so: http://jsfiddle.net/wg8mh47r/ Also, I'd strongly recommend you remove the inline styles and move all the CSS to separate document.

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Comment: Is this what you require? http://jsfiddle.net/wg8mh47r/2/

Comment: I apologize for not creating a fiddle, Fahad thanks for doing so. That is certainly what it looks like with the blue div overlapping, which is not what I want. The blue div should display at the bottom of the top div.

Comment: Lindsay: thanks for your input, I just pulled the html and css out of my project for the purpose of asking a question here, which is why it is in the same "file". Looks like the css got dropped it the js box :)

Comment: So you want it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/t7Lws0cx/

Comment: No, I don't want the two to overlap each other at all, I want the blue div to display underneath the gray one.